# Text with line breaks returns \r\n in text through Ajax/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Code that works fine except for the issue of passing a value back and forth between JavaScript, Ajax, and PHP. Using TinyMCE as the editor, when I add a paragraph break in the text, save the data (passing it through JavaScript/Ajax and PHP to do so) the text appears to be okay. Here's the JavaScript and Ajax code -- this works, it passes the data correctly to the PHP program when the submit button is clicked:

```
  // save the main who's who form data:
  $("form#who_main").submit(function(e)
  {
     e.preventDefault();

     // first thing, clear out the message div used for this (if there's anything there):
     document.getElementById("who_message").innerHTML = "";

     // because we're using TinyMCE, need to replace value in that into the textarea
     // so that when JavaScript gathers the formData it is getting it from the textarea
     // controls (it doesn't know what to do with TinyMCE):
     var shortbio = tinymce.get('shortbio').getContent();
     document.getElementById( "shortbio" ).value = shortbio;
     var user_notes = tinymce.get('user_notes').getContent();
     document.getElementById( "user_notes" ).value = user_notes;
     var admin_notes = tinymce.get('admin_notes').getContent();
     document.getElementById( "admin_notes" ).value = admin_notes;

     // this loads all the controls of the form rather than doing one at a time and fumbling
     // with the file object ...:
     var formData = new FormData(this);

     // ajax call to attempt to upload and save the image:
     $.ajax
     ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $History_html_RootPath; ?>admin/AjaxCalls/who_update_main_save.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json", // return value is json array
        processData : false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
           // need to see if we have an error, if so, display it, otherwise,
           // we should hopefully have success ...
           if ( data[0].toLowerCase().includes( "error" ) )
           {
              var errormsg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>"+data+"</div>";
              document.getElementById("who_message").innerHTML = errormsg;
              return;
           }
           else
           {
              // success!

              // update things on screen, so we don't get confused using the data array returned
              // from PHP:
              document.getElementById("namecode").value                = data[0];
              document.getElementById("region").value                  = data[1];
              document.getElementById("local").value                   = data[2];
              document.getElementById("preferredtitle").value          = data[3];
              document.getElementById("shortbio").value                = data[4];
              tinymce.get('shortbio').setContent( data[4] );
              document.getElementById("headshotphoto").value           = data[5];
              document.getElementById("photographername").value        = data[6];
              document.getElementById("photographerlink").value        = data[7];
              document.getElementById("user_notes").value              = data[8];
              tinymce.get('user_notes').setContent( data[8] );
              document.getElementById("admin_notes").value             = data[9];
              tinymce.get('admin_notes').setContent( data[9] );

              // clear out the upload file control:
              //document.getElementById("headshotphoto").value           = "";

              // change the message:
              var message = "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
                  message += "<b>Success!</b> This data has been updated in the <i>holding</i> table.";
                  message += "</div>";
              document.getElementById("who_message").innerHTML = message;
              return;
           }
        }  // end success
     }); // end ajax call
  }) // end of code associated with who_main submit
```

The PHP file receives the data via post, and I use the PHP function mysqli_real_escape_string() to deal with issues. The one problem with doing this is that it appears to insert backslashes for quotes (single and double), and so on. I just had a thought that **might be the cause** of the problem, and that is the use of this function, I am not sure. I will test it, but in the meantime. ... I save the data to the table and all is good. If there's a paragraph break, the proper tags are saved out into the table. 
     <p>Some text</p><p>More text 'quoted text'</p>

When I pass the data back using JSON encoding:

```
$returndata = array();
$returndata[0]  = $namecode;
$returndata[1]  = $region;
$returndata[2]  = $local;
$returndata[3] = $preferredtitle;
$returndata[4] = $shortbio;
$returndata[5] = $photo_file;
$returndata[6] = $photographername;
$returndata[7] = $photographerlink;
$returndata[8] = $user_notes;
$returndata[9] = $admin_notes;
// done-done:
echo json_encode( $returndata );
return;
```

The code above (the javascript/Ajax code) comes back looking like:
    <p>Some text</p>\r\n<p>More text \'quoted text\'</p>

I need to not have the \r\n and \' (or \") showing up in my text. If I were to save it again like that it gets weirder as the backslashes get duplicated and more. I am sure there's some *thing* I am missing, but I don't know what it is. This is making me crazy because everything else works exactly as I need it to.

**NOTE** Added code that I have attempted to use, in PHP, to deal with "escapes", it works for single and double quotes, but not for the \r\n characters -- instead it just strips out the backslash:

```
function remove_escapes( $string )
{
   $string = str_replace ( "\'", "&#039;", $string ); // convert single quote
   $string = str_replace ( "\"", "&quot;", $string ); // convert double-quote
   $string = str_replace ( "\r\n", "", $string ); // remove \r\n
   $string = str_replace ( "\\", "", $string ); // remove slash
   // anything else giving us heartburn?
   return $string;
} // eof: remove_escapes()
```

If I use this with the json array, I get the letters rn inserted between paragraphs:

```
$returndata[8] =  remove_escapes( $user_notes );
$returndata[9] =  remove_escapes( $admin_notes );
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe doing something like `data.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')` this will replace all newline markers with the html newline or `data.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>')` to look for the characters rather than a newline marker

Comment: I have done some testing to examine the data and it appears to be happening because of the mysqli_real_escape_string() function. If I take that out, I am not getting the \r\n codes. So perhaps the jquery post is passing things in a way I don't need that function?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some testing to examine the data and it appears to be happening because of the mysqli_real_escape_string() function when I get the data from the $_POST() array. If I take that out, I am not getting the \r\n codes. So perhaps the jquery post is passing things in a way I don't need that function? Further testing on the three different text controls shows it working without the need to use mysqli_real_escape_string, and I have some extra functionality to deal with looking for JavaScript and such in the text, so I may be able to simplify the code. Unless someone can tell me a reason not to do this ...?

Comment: What about SQL injection? I am a bit concerned that you do not know what you are doing.

Comment: Do you have a solution for the issue at hand? I do understand the concerns about SQL Injection. However, I also cannot have the data being screwed up this way ...

Comment: Well, I don't think just providing a solutions does work in this case. You have read what `mysql_real_escape_string` does? Why is it even a problem to save values that include encoded characters? This is not weird at all, but common practice.

Comment: Because they display on the screen that way in TinyMCE. Imagine, if you will, a user who sees things embedded in the text like \r\n, or \' or \" ... I have to think about the end-user as well.

Comment: So the trick is to properly decode it when it comes out the database :)

Comment: This is not a case of it coming back out of the database, it is being passed back through the JSON encode and put back into the controls in case something got modified along the way. What gets bad is \' if the user then modifies or simply saves again becomes \\' and then \\\' and so on ...

Comment: Jep, because it is automatically escaped (or through `mysqli_real_escape_string`). Just look in your database to see how it is encoded/escaped. Then, decode it server or client side.

Comment: I have attempted to do this. I have a php function (which I will have to place in the original post above) called remove_escapes(), that is not dealing with \r\n properly, and is just stripping out the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is there so that special characters are escaped, this helps prevent hacking attacks like sql injection.

Comment: I understand that, and if I am using standard HTML forms and posting through HTML rather than JavaScript/Ajax, it works just fine, but when I do it with JavaScript and Ajax I am getting weirdness that I cannot get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the only solution I can find is to continue with mysqli_real_escape_string(), but when passing the information back, after saving the changes, re-load the data from the table, which does not display the escape characters and therefore avoids the issue. It seems like a lot of extra data processing, but it's only ever (in my code) one row at a time that is being passed back and forth.

Comment: No one should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, write prepared statements.